# Upload video to third party from you website, missing FilePath

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, file-upload

have an asp.net site and need to upload video to third party.

From the api I have all the security credentials needed, have endpoint url to upload video to.

But I can NOT get the FilePath only file name off the user computer.

Do I need to first upload the file to my server and only then push it to thirdparty endponit?  That would mean that I would need to run a cleanup every X time to delete files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is code I tried:

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload" runat="server" />
 <input id="File1" type="file" runat="server" />
```

For both of these I could only get the fileName and Not filePath.

But I need to pass the FILE PATH to third party api to use in endpoint url,  if not it would meanm I would need to upload the file to my server and then pass filePAth from my server. But would also mena I would need to delete the file from my server once thirdParty process done. 
I can not believe that uploading to server is the solution.

Comment: Sounds like you've tried something already, where is your code so that SO can see whats not right.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are correct in your assumption that you will need to 1st upload the file on your server and then move it to the service.
I don't believe you will be able to get the file path from the client's machine for security reasons.